# ios landscape-orientation screen in portrait orientation results

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[when first entry, the result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUtsI.png)

[App into the background and back, the orientation is normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Lee.jpg)

this is the code for the ViewController：

```
DDYLoveAutoHallViewController *autoHallViewController = [[DDYLoveAutoHallViewController alloc] initWithEvent:room.currentEventID type:AHRoom_System];
[self presentViewController:autoHallViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

i don't know why, the project is a litter old, it support iOS5 before.

Comment: Please, clarify. Your question in not clear. The problem is not related to how you create the ViewController.

Comment: Yes, the problem is when I present the ViewController, the screen show like the first picture, and when i let the app into to background ,then back app, the orientation will normal display, the supportedInterfaceOrientations functions has implementation.

Comment: Can you show the code how are you managing constraints or handling orientation in DDYLoveAutoHallViewController?

Comment: I had solve it through this code：
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];

Answer (score 1):

Without understanding on how do you manage layouts it is difficult to give the exact reason, caused you problem, but, i can suggest you couple of little advices:

- try to re-check orientation in - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews, and you can re-position things from there. (probably it will work and solve your problem, but it is not very clean solution, because may be called a few times at time, knowing this you can make it cleaner)
- play generally with the methods of layout-lifecycle, to detect where are things is going wrong. Dive deeper in modern way to layout on iOS. (better solution)

Answer (score 0):

Without more details regarding your specific problem, and how you are detecting and adjusting the orientation, it is hard to understand the exact problem, but here are some observations I have made, working with iOS 5.x based (and earlier), apps, that might point you in the correct direction:

[1] Earlier versions of iOS set some defaults, before actually interrogating the hardware to determine orientation and app frame size information.

a) Initially orientation is set to PORTRAIT - along with portrait orientation frame dimensions - during initialization. (This is WRONG if you device is in landscape orientation - so DON’T USE this initial info). (left over from earlier “iPhone only days” - I guess)

b) This continues to be incorrect at the “ViewDidLoad” and “applicationDidBecomeActive” timeframes (at least for my app - possibly - depends on loading time etc…)

c) The correct orientation is yielded later, via the “didChangeStatusBarOrientation method invocation.  You can use this information with Window.frame.size information, to display the correct image with the correct size. 
This is effectively the trigger to indicate the orientation request will now be correct.
One stategy might be to : Don’t try to display anything until the “didChangeStatusBarOrientation” message has been received.

[2] Non-Code Solution: (using Settings : Supported interface Orientations)

a) If the app is designed to always work in the Landscape orientation, make sure this is reflected in the app settings/info.plist.   I would suggest only allowing 1 “supported interface Orientations”, that being Landscape, and all views would reflect the landscape size and orientation.(if your code is not specifically setting or doing anything with orientation, then this might be a solution by setting everything to "landscape only". Otherwise this option probably won't help.)

[3] Last Solution:

a) If you can change the base iOS version higher, the iOS6 and greater versions initialize the orientation and frame sizes earlier in the initialization cycle, so the problem may just disappear due to this.

Here is some of the code used to discover this, along with output below (using an original ipad as a sample, in this case…running iOS 5.1.1 - started in landscape and orientation was unchanged)

```
-(void) OrientationAndScreenSizeHELPER : (NSString *)fromObject
{
    //from:

    // NSLog(@"%s:%d someObject=%@", __func__, __LINE__, someObject);


    CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen ]applicationFrame];//using frame so status bar is not part of calculations.

    appFrame = [[self.viewController view]frame];//using frame so status bar is not part of calculations.

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    NSLog(@"orientation[%ld] at time[%@]    width[%ld] height[%ld]",
      (long)orientation,
      fromObject,
      (long int)appFrame.size.width,
      (long int)appFrame.size.height);

}

**Output:**
orientation[1] at time[ViewDidLoad Orientation]    width[768] height[1024]
orientation[1] at time[applicationDidBecomeActive]    width[768] height[1024]
orientation[3] at time[didChangeStatusBarOrientation]    width[1024] height[768]
```